# Is there any way or software by which I can monitor my home WiFi?

Tags: open-source, networking, network-monitor, wifi

I am really not into networking rather than coding, but I want to know if there is a way or software by which:

1. I can limit the speed of my WiFi users.
2. I can see what sites or URLs they are surfing.
3. I can see how much bandwidth are they using.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can find such information when you log in into admin panel of your router. There is custom firmware (such as Tomato firmware) that you can install on your router and have more detailed information compared to stock firmware.